# Android Studio update broke my emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, haxm

I just did an update to Android Studio 2.0 and several components. Now whenever I try to run an emulator, it gives an error saying

```
CPU acceleration status: HAXM must be updated (version 1.1.4 < 6.0.1).
```

I've checked. HAXM is updated to 6.0.1. I've restarted, rebuilt an emulator from scratch, and none of that helps.

Comment: you should repost this issue to google, maybe because of android studio 2.0 still in preview

Answer (score 15):

I just needed to run sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe

Comment: Thanks. Idk why, but we must manually install after downloading an update from HAMX

Answer (score 12):

If you're using Mac, just running the dmg or silent_install.sh will solve the issue.

dmg's path is (silent install script is in the same dir also):

path_android_sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM_6.0.1.dmg

Comment: This worked for me, but bazaar it wasn't automatically executed during the upgrade process in Android Studio, or at least some kind of message letting you know you had to run this.

Answer (score 9):

1. Uninstall HAXM from SDK manager
2. Again install HAXM in SDK manager
3. Now goto sdk_path/extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and double click on intelhaxm-android.exe
4. After completion of above steps try to run emulator.
   (I got same problem, did above steps worked as expected.)

Comment: Not sure if uninstalling is really necessary (I doubt it) but it works.

Comment: I had this problem on OS X. You'll also find a `silent_install.sh` in that directory. On OS X a quick `sudo sh silent_install.sh` fixed the problem for me. I also had to quick VirtualBox as it clashes with the android simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Using: **Windows 10**

Tested: **May, 03, 2016**

This is what worked for me without uninstalling anything:

**1. Download INTEL HAXM from Intel site**

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement

**2. Locate the HAXM folder in your PC** - in my case this is the path:

C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

*Note: if you can't find the folder, you probably don't have HAXM installed and this steps will not work for you*

**3. Extract downloaded file (in my case --> *haxm-windows_v6_0_1.zip* <--) in HAXM folder from step 2 and overwrite all duplicate files if needed**

**4. Install the updated version by running --> *intelhaxm-android.exe* <-- located in folder from step 2 and follow installation process**

Comment: This is so far, seems the most straight forward answer addressing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, Google already is working on new built from scratch emulator, so it might be some problem with exisitng ones

I recommend you nowadays, as you have upgraded your Android Studio to 2.0 version use temporary Genymotion emulator: https://www.genymotion.com

It uses HAXM, it's much faster than Google's default emulator, and has some useful features like faking GPS localization.

Give it a try. I'm already using it and that's why I am highly recommend you this.

---

Sorry, that I haven't respond clearly to your question, but it seems to be an Android problem, and you should to downgrade it to previous one.

To avoid that, please try to use Genymotion emulator.

Answer (score -1):

We need to install intel HAXM updated version ( search in google ) after issue resolved now I can see my emulator.

Thanks